# How to setup a conditional breakpoint with simics command?

Tags: simics

It looks like Simics Eclipse can setup a conditional breakpoint, but I didn't find any `condition` parameters with `break-*` commands. Is that possible to setup the break condition with simics commands?

Another question is how can I setup dynamic printf with simics commands?

with gdb, I can use this to logging breakpoint hits, how can I do the same thing with simics?

```
(gdb) b malloc
(gdb) commands
> silent
> printf "malloc hit"
> cont
> end
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simics does not have conditional breakpoints in the built-in breakpoint commands. If you want to do something like that, write a script branch that waits for the breakpoint and then inspect the state.  The commands are intentionally fairly basic.

What is a "dynamic printf" in this context?

It might be simpler to use Simics gdb-remote to connect a gdb debugger to Simics and use that to debug your target software.

To see all breakpoint hits, Simics will tend to write a message each time the breakpoint hit:

```
simics> bp.memory.break -x 0xffff0000 0x100000
Breakpoint 2: break on 'x' access to 0xffff_0000 len=1_048_576 in board.cell_context
simics> r
[board.cell_context] Breakpoint 2: board.cell_context 'x' access to v:0xfffffff0
simics> r
[board.cell_context] Breakpoint 2: board.cell_context 'x' access to v:0xfffffff1
simics> r
[board.cell_context] Breakpoint 2: board.cell_context 'x' access to v:0xfffffff2 len=2
```

If you want to act on a breakpoint hit, use a script to react and print whatever your want. Like this, for example.  If a script branch picks up the breakpoint, Simics will not stop its execution.

```
simics> script-branch {
.......   while(TRUE) {
.......     bp.wait-for-breakpoint 2
.......     echo (ptime)
.......   } 
....... }
2
simics> r
"board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0]"
[["board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0]", 8, 8, 4e-09]]
"board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0]"
[["board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0]", 9, 9, 4.5e-09]]
"board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0]"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but `script-branch` still can not work properly. I compiled a helloworld.c, setted up a breakpoint at `main()`, created a script-branch just like yours. But Simics stopped its exection at `main()`, the message is `[tcf] Breakpoint 1 on execution in context mb.cpu0.core[1][0]`, `echo (ptime)` never been exectuted.

Comment: The breakpoint was setted by `bp.source_location.break main`. But I found if the breakpoint was created by `bp.memory.break -x 0x4010f6`, the script-branch works properly. Is there any difference between these two breakpoints? Why the first one can not work with script-branch?

Comment: Are you using the correct breakpoint ID in each case?  You should really do something akin to `$b = (bp....break...)`  and then do `bp.wait-for-breakpoint $b`.

Comment: Yes, the breakpoint ID is correct, I used to find out the breakpoint ID by `bp.list`. I just tried with `$b = (bp....break...)`, and then do `bp.wait-for-breakpoint $b`, Simics will stop its exectution at the breakpoint, which was exepected not.

Comment: No, that does not sound right.